# Using IATI data to perform Impact assesment with Directed acyclic graphs (DAGs)

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs

Has anyone tried to perform Impact Assessment using Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) with data published on the International Aid Transparency Initiative Data Repository: https://iatiregistry.org/ Would be interested to see a reproducible notebook similar to what is presented here: https://evalf21.classes.andrewheiss.com/example/

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad, and is essentially asking for off-site resources, which I'm afraid is off topic. If you can show what you have tried so far, and explain where you got stuck, that would be on-topic.

Comment: right! you have a point - will update here as soon as I have more details